# strange error with removeProcessor?

Tags: java, libgdx

I use a KeyUp event to remove the event of a stage object. What I did:

```
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == consoleKeyToggle) {
        show = !show;
        if (show)
            framework.AddInputListener(stage);
        else
            framework.RemoveInputListener(stage);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and in framework object I have 2 functions:

```
@Override
public void AddInputListener(InputProcessor input) {
    multiplexer.addProcessor(input);
}

@Override
public void RemoveInputListener(InputProcessor input) {
    multiplexer.removeProcessor(input);
}
```

AddInputListener is fine, but when RemoveInputListener is called, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 2 >= 2
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.get(Array.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.keyUp(InputMultiplexer.java:76)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:288)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:199)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These functions are being called by input-multiplexer and you are modifying it INSIDE those functions (event-callbacks).
In usual cases this should be avoided.
But if you can't find a better alternative logic, you can try replacing

```
framework.AddInputListener(stage);
```

with

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        framework.AddInputListener(stage);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.